# Adding calcite UDF with one argument as SQL Type (varchar,int etc.) like CONVERT() in SQL

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions, apache-calcite

I am trying to work with Apache Calcite's SQlParser and I need to implement a udf with syntax similar to `CONVERT()` function i.e., `FUNC_NAME(col_name,SQL_TYPE)`
How can I achieve the same behaviour?

Edit: 
With return type same as second argument of function. Ex. SQL_TYPE for above mentioned case

Comment: Function in MySQL must have definite output datatype - so it is unsolvable.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to mention that function's return type will be same as second argument. Actually I am trying to implement CONVERT() function as my calcite SQL Parser is not parsing the sql queries with convert() like Select convert(col_name,char) as char_col from table_name.

Comment: *function's return type will be same as second argument.* As I have said above - it is impossible. But this not needed for MySQL - its datatype system is soft. *my calcite SQL Parser is not parsing the sql queries with convert() like `Select convert(col_name,char) as char_col from table_name`* - this function usage in your query makes no sense until you need to change character set, use CAST() instead.